# use html5 output tag to display javascript variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

Sorry if this is a silly question, but I've been trying to use AJAX to display my javascript variables in 'real time' with little luck. I'm definitely a beginner though so this could be the problem haha- When I see the AJAX code, it always seems to require an additional url that it refreshes, but I just want to refresh the javascript variables on click.

http://jsfiddle.net/bagelpirate/m9Pm2/

```
<script>
var one = 0;
var two = 0;
var three = 0;
</script>

<body>
<div id="div_1">
    One: <script>document.write(one)</script> | 
    Two: <script>document.write(two)</script> | 
    Three: <script>document.write(three)</script>
</div>

<div id="div_2">

    <img id="mine" src="https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/3170725828/ac1d6621fc3c3ecaa541d8073d4421cc.jpeg" onclick="one++;" />

    <img id="forest" src="http://blogs.dallasobserver.com/sportatorium/No.%202.png" onclick="two++;" />

    <img id="farm" src="https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/3732261215/bd041d1f0948b6ea0493f90507d67ef2.png" onclick="three++;" /> 

</div>
</body>
```

As you can see in the above code, when a user clicks one of the images, I want to increment the count and display it at the top of the page. I found the HTML5 output tag, and was wondering if it's possible to use this to display the javascript variable in real time? Everything I've read seems to imply it can't be done because the output tag only works on forms? Anyway, I figured it couldn't hurt to ask!

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Don't use `document.write`.

Comment: You want something like Knockout.js to bind a ViewModel to your HTML.

Comment: What you are doing is not AJAX... it's just regular old javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use document.write to write to the DOM after it's finished loading. You have tagged your question with jQuery, so I'll assume you can use that to update things. Instead, update the DOM from within your script block. Here is an example that might help you get started.

http://jsfiddle.net/prxBb/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var one = 0;
        var two = 0;
        var three = 0;

        $('img#mine').click(function() {
            one++;
            $('span#one').html(one);
        });
         $('img#forest').click(function() {
            two++;
            $('span#two').html(two);
        });
         $('img#farm').click(function() {
            three++;
            $('span#three').html(three);
        });
    });
</script>

<body>
<div id="div_1">
    One: <span id="one"></span> | 
    Two: <span id="two"></span> | 
    Three: <span id="three"></span>
</div>

<div id="div_2">

<img id="mine" src="https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/3170725828/ac1d6621fc3c3ecaa541d8073d4421cc.jpeg" />

<img id="forest" src="http://blogs.dallasobserver.com/sportatorium/No.%202.png" />

<img id="farm" src="https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/3732261215/bd041d1f0948b6ea0493f90507d67ef2.png" /> 

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to follow and get it working! http://jsfiddle.net/bagelpirate/mKfEk/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try putting all your variables inside a named object, iterating through it at predefined interval and displaying the values.

```
var varContainer = {
    one:0,
    two:0,
    three:0
};
jQuery("#div_2 img").on('click',function(){
    jQuery.each(varContainer,function(key,value){
        //Add key + value to the DOM
        if(jQuery("."+key+value).length<1)
            jQuery("#div_2").append("<div class='"+key+value+"'></div>");
        var newHtmlVal= "<p><span>Var name: "+key+"</span><br><span>Value: "+value+"</span>";
        jQuery("."+key+value).html();
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="div_2">

</div>
```

Of course the script could be upgraded to look through each variable recursivley in case of nested objects/arrays...

Hope this helps!